# jQuery select and uncheck a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have a list of checkboxes in my document.

If I do

```
$(".myCheckbox input[type='checkbox']")
```

I see

```
    jQuery.fn.init(6) [input#myCheckbox1_0, input#myCheckbox2_0, input#myCheckbox2_1, input#myCheckbox2_2, input#myCheckbox2_3, input#myCheckbox2_4, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".myCheckbox input[type='checkbox']"]
0
:
input#myCheckbox1_0
1
:
input#myCheckbox2_0
2
:
input#myCheckbox2_1
3
:
input#myCheckbox2_2
4
:
input#myCheckbox2_3
5
:
input#myCheckbox2_4
context
:
document
length
:
6
prevObject
:
n.fn.init [document, context: document]
selector
:
".myCheckbox input[type='checkbox']"
```

I want to get a reference to the `input#myCheckbox2_2` and uncheck it using jQuery.

I tried

```
$("input#myCheckbox2_2 input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",false);
```

and

```
$(".myCheckbox input[type='checkbox']")[2].prop("checked",false);
```

It did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post HTML and SCRIPT in a [mcve]

Comment: Why not `$("#myCheckbox2_2").prop("checked",false)` by the way. It would be SO  EASIER if we had HTML to look at

Answer (score 1):

Use `.eq()`:https://api.jquery.com/eq/
**Set 3 inside because `input#myCheckbox2_2` in 3rd place**
that the reason it does not work:`$(".myCheckbox input[type='checkbox']")[2].prop("checked",false);`

```js
$(".myCheckbox input[type='checkbox']").eq(3).prop("checked",false)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myCheckbox">
  <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" checked="true">
  <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" checked="true">
  <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" checked="true">
  <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" checked="true">
  <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" checked="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one, please.**

```
$(".myCheckbox input#myCheckbox2_2[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
```

**Better use only id, cause id need to be unique.**

```
$("#myCheckbox2_2").prop("checked", false);
```

**I think you have issue with your snippens:**

1. $(".myCheckbox input[type='checkbox']")[2].prop("checked",false);
2. $("input#myCheckbox2_2 input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",false);

**Here you are trying to find:**

1. 3 element instead of 4. You need to replace [2] with [3]
2. input inside input. But you have not any nested inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector name is incorrect. No need for the space and additional value. This should work.

```
$('input#myCheckbox2_2').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Even `$('#myCheckbox2_2').prop('checked', false);`